Python equivalent of the Perl ".." flip-flop operator
What is the Python equivalent of the Perl ".." (range, or flip-flop) operator?
for ( qw( foo bar barbar baz bazbaz bletch ) ) { 
    print "$_\n" if /ar.a/ .. /az\w/;
}

Output:
barbar
baz
bazbaz

The Python workaround that I am aware of includes generator expression and indexing with the help of enumerate, but this seems cumbersome:
import re

lst = 'foo bar barbar baz bazbaz bletch'.split()
idx_from = list(i for i, el in enumerate(lst) if re.search(r'ar.a', el))[0]
idx_to   = list(i for i, el in enumerate(lst) if re.search(r'az\w', el))[0]

lst_subset = lst[ idx_from : (idx_to+1)]
print(lst_subset)
# ['barbar', 'baz', 'bazbaz']

Note:
I am looking for just one range. There is currently no need to have multiple ranges.

I think that your best bet for a clean solution would in fact be iterating over the list of strings, using lambda functions with regex as your start and end conditions. I can't think of a nice way to handle it.

Your workaround is incorrect since it only finds one range.

@ikegami I am looking for just one range. There is currently no need to have multiple ranges. Sorry for not making this clear. I edited the answer.

In the future, please ask what something in Perl does, or how to do something in Python. These are completely different questions.

@ikegami This question already asks the latter, and not the former.

@no comment It does neither. It asks to translate code. It should have asked the later. That's my point. They didn't even want a translation, but only a subset of the functionality of the flip-flop. It even required edits to get where we are now.

When the operands aren't simple numbers, EXPR1 .. EXPR2 in scalar context is equivalent to following (except for the scope created by do { }):
do {
   state $hidden_state = 0;
   if ( $hidden_state ) {
      ++$hidden_state;
   } else {
      $hidden_state = 1 if EXPR1;
   }

   my $rv = $hidden_state;

   # Or `$hidden_state > 1 && EXPR2` for `...`.
   if ( $hidden_state && EXPR2 ) {
      $rv .= "E0";
      $hidden_state = 0;
   }

   $rv
}

Since you only care whether the flip-flop returns true or false, the above simplifies to the following:
do {
   state $hidden_state = false;
   $hidden_state ||= EXPR1;
   my $rv = $hidden_state;
   $hidden_state &&= EXPR2;
   $rv
}

Now we have to translate this. Since the flip-flip is usually used as a generator, that's what I'll create.
def flipflop( enumerable, start_cond, end_cond ):
   state = False
   for val in enumerable:
      if not state:
         state = start_cond( val )
      if state:
         yield val
      if state:
         state = end_cond( val )

import re

lst = 'foo bar barbar baz bazbaz bletch'.split()

for x in flipflop( lst, lambda v: re.search( r'ar.a', v ), lambda v: re.search( r'az\w', v ) ):
   print( x )


Added translation

... is slightly different.  I think just $hidden_state > 1 && EXPR2 instead?

oh, missed that, sorry

Yes, ... could be implemented that way.

What's the grounds for a -1 ... ??  If the anyone could explain that'd be great

@zdim, I didn't originally have a translation

@zdim https://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=168266 applies

Basic (Attempt This Online!):
import re

in_range = False
for word in 'foo bar barbar baz bazbaz bletch'.split():
    if not in_range:
        in_range = re.search(r'ar.a', word)
    if in_range:
        print(word)
    if in_range:
        in_range = not re.search(r'az\w', word)

With a class (Attempt This Online!):
import re

class Within:
    def __init__(self, flip, flop):
        self.flip = flip
        self.flop = flop
        self.state = False
    def __bool__(self):
        if not self.state and self.flip():
            self.state = True
        result = self.state
        if self.state and self.flop():
            self.state = False
        return result

within = Within(
    lambda: re.search(r'ar.a', word),
    lambda: re.search(r'az\w', word),
)
for word in 'foo bar barbar baz bazbaz bletch'.split():
    if within:
        print(word)

Itertoolsish (Attempt This Online!):
import re

def flipflop(iterable, flip, flop):
    state = False
    for x in iterable:
        if not state:
            state = flip(x)
        if state:
            yield x
        if state:
            state = not flop(x)

for word in flipflop(
    'foo bar barbar baz bazbaz bletch'.split(),
    re.compile(r'ar.a').search,
    re.compile(r'az\w').search
):
    print(word)

Or without a state variable, the outer loop searches for an element to enter the range and the inner loop searches for an element to exit the range (Attempt This Online!):
import re

def flipflop(iterable, enter, exit):
    it = iter(iterable)
    for x in it:
        if enter(x):
            yield x
            if not exit(x):
                for x in it:
                    yield x
                    if exit(x):
                        break

for word in flipflop(
    'foo bar barbar baz bazbaz bletch'.split(),
    re.compile(r'ar.a').search,
    re.compile(r'az\w').search
):
    print(word)


Warning as I do not know perl enough to understand what .. does I implemented something akin to Ranges from GNU AWK, which hopefully will be close enough for your use case.
There is no direct equivalent available as far as know, therefore I propose implement this using flag following way
import re
def get_re_range(iterable, start_pattern, end_pattern):
    flag = False
    for element in iterable:
        if re.search(start_pattern, element):
            flag = True
        if flag:
            yield element
        if re.search(end_pattern, element):
            flag = False
words = "foo bar barbar baz bazbaz bletch".split()
for word in get_re_range(words, r'ar.a', r'az\w'):
    print(word)

gives output
barbar
baz
bazbaz

Observe order of ifs to get inclusive-inclusive behavior.
